# Unable to scan all Urls of site map at once

Tags: security, burp

I am using Burp Suite Professional 2020.5  I browsed all urls of a website they were displayed in target site map then i added the host to scope. After clicking on the main url of website, if i scan it through audit and crawl options, only one url is scanned. How do i make burp scan the complete host (including all browsed urls) in a single scan? We are able to add all the urls manually in scan but how can we automatically scan all the urls at once?